# how can i write the max value of different consecutive values in the new column by length

Tags: sql-server

i have a data frame as "a".
a:
[,1] 1  2  3  0 1 2 0 [,2] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 [,3] 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 and dim(a)=7*3

i want to create a new column including maximum value for each set of consecutive numbers till 0. and calculate for next set till next zero. like this:
result:
[,1] 3 3  3  0 2 2 0 [,2] 0 0 3 3 3 0 1 [,3] 5 5 5 5 5 0 0

unfortunatly i couldn't put the picture of my data frame(a).
please help me to write the right function

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: Please give your expected answer for the data you have supplied and the logic you used to get it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a difference between first column ([1,]) and d1 you will get something like this:

```
SELECT id,d1
   ,id-d1 as diff_d1
FROM Table1
```

output:

```
id  d1  diff_d1
1   1   0
2   2   0
3   3   0
4   0   4
5   1   4
6   2   4
7   0   7
```

Doing a max on [d1] and grouping by [diff_d1] column you will get : [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af16d31ed540678d205ef6a0cc143638)

```
maxD1
3
2
0
```

Putting all together

```
;WITH cteSource AS
(SELECT
   id,
   d1,d2,d3
   ,MAX(d1) OVER(PARTITION BY id-d1 ORDER BY id
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
             AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)as maxD1
   ,MAX(d2) OVER(PARTITION BY id-d2 ORDER BY id
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
             AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)as maxD2
   ,MAX(d3) OVER(PARTITION BY id-d3 ORDER BY id
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
             AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)as maxD3
FROM Table1
)    
SELECT id
     ,CASE WHEN d1<> 0 THEN maxD1
           ELSE 0  END AS d1
    ,CASE WHEN d2 <>  0 THEN maxD2
           ELSE 0  END AS d2
    ,CASE WHEN d3 <>  0 THEN maxD3
           ELSE 0  END AS d3
FROM cteSource
```

Output:

```
id  d1  d2  d3
1   3   0   5
2   3   0   5
3   3   3   5
4   0   3   5
5   2   3   5
6   2   0   0
7   0   1   0
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e4db6d63115a53659ba5f8474a1956b)

Comment: thanks for your answer. my real file is big. unfortunatly i couldn't do your comment because i am new in r. can you write the exact commands for each steps from the first?

Comment: The exact command is starting with `;WITH cteSource AS...` , the first part is just an example to better understand the logic behind it